# How to delete a unidirectional, one to one mapping from database, using jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to delete both the row in Merchant table and the row in the Address table from the database. The Merchant has address_id in its table. I have created DAOs for both Merchant and Address. 
How can I do this by only using Entity Manager? 
I have left out the imports, and getters and setters. 
It seems to only delete the row in the Merchant table, and leave the row in the address table. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Whenever I delete the merchant entity, it keeps the address id, and does not delete the corresponding address in the Address table. I don't understand why.

```
@Entity
public class Merchant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    public Merchant() {
    }
}
```

```
public class MerchantDAO {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hamzaspersistenceunit");

    public void persist(Merchant merchant) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(merchant);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public void removeMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.contains(merchant) ? merchant : em.merge(merchant));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;

    public Address(String name, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

}
```

```
public class AddressDAO {
    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hamzaspersistenceunit");

    public AddressDAO() {

    }

    public void persist(Address address) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(address);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        em.remove(em.contains(address) ? address : em.merge(address));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {

        // creating and persisting an addresss
        Address address = new Address("123", "123", "123", "123", "123");
        AddressDAO addressdao = new AddressDAO();
        addressdao.persist(address);

        // creating and persisting a merchant
        Merchant merchant = new Merchant();
        merchant.setName("merchant");
        merchant.setAddress(address);
        MerchantDAO merchantdao = new MerchantDAO();
        merchantdao.persist(merchant);

        // removing merchant
        merchantdao.removeMerchant(merchant);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try annotating the `address` field in the `Merchant` entity with `@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)`. By default this option is set to `false` so the remove operation is not cascaded to the `Address` entity.

Update: The correct resolution for this problem is to use `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`

Comment: I added that to my Merchant class, still nothing happened. I get the same problem...

Comment: What about `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`?

Comment: @MatthewFormosa: Comments can be deleted later on, but the answers remain. Edit your answer.